# GAPIC client of ResourceManager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-resource-manager

I'm trying to create a java client listing all projects in GCP, I've used `google-cloud-resourcemanager` as mentioned in the documentation. It works fine but I keep getting ResourceManager is deprecated. `v3 GAPIC client of ResourceManager is now available` . Not sure what is a Gapic client and how do I use it?

Comment: Your question should include the source code and import library statements. Most likely you are using an **old** SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same deprecation message, and after some research I believe that the message is terribly misleading - there actually is no `ResourceManager` equivalent in the new design, it has been broken apart into a number of different clients. In particular, the deprecation message for `ResourceManager.get()` says `Please use com.google.cloud.resourcemanager.v3.ProjectsClient.getProject() instead`.

(There are also now separate `OrganizationsClient` and `FoldersClient` objects as well)